# TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module) when trying to use rspec

Tags: ruby, string, rspec

Checking containment of a substring in a string.

I think I'm using the right syntax as documented [here](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html), but it's not working for me.  What am I missing?

```
>> require 'rspec-expectations'
=> true
>> s = 'potato'
=> "potato"
>> s.include?('tat')
=> true
>> s.should include('tat')
TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module)
    from (irb):4:in `include'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

Should expects a matcher object so simplest way to answer your question would be:

```
>> require 'rspec-expectations'
=> true
>> s = 'potato'
=> "potato"
>> s.should RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Include.new('tat')
=> true
```

Lets talk about different matcher for a while **eq** (because there is something about **include**)

```
>> require 'rspec-expectations'
=> true
>> s = 'potato'
=> "potato"
>> s.should eq('potato')
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for main:Object
```

To get **eq** to work we can include [RSpec::Matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers.rb) module(method definitions start at line 193)

```
>> require 'rspec-expectations'
=> true
>> s = 'potato'
=> "potato"
>> include RSpec::Matchers
>> s.should eq('potato')
=> true
```

So what you are missing is to extend your object with RSpec::Matchers module methods or simply passing a matcher to should method.

Problem with **include** matcher in IRB is still present(not 100% sure why):

```
>> require 'rspec-expectations'
=> true
>> s = 'potato'
=> "potato"
>> include RSpec::Matchers
>> s.should include('tat')
TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module)
```

It might have something to do with working in a context of a main object:

```
>> self
=> main
>> self.class
=> Object
>> Object.respond_to(:include)
=> false
>> Object.respond_to(:include, true) #check private and protected methods as well
=> true
```

Object have a private method include. Include method from RSpec::Matchers never gets chance to get called. If you wrap it in a class that will include RSpec::Matchers everyting should be working.

Rspec does it with MiniTest::Unit::TestCase [RSpec::Matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers.rb) (line 168)

Comment: No, doesn't seem to be IRB glitch because it happens when executing from a script as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `context` or `it` block around the expectation.